# Sqlite pragma settings with SQlite for Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, sqlite

We are trying to make Pragma settings for our SQLite database. We are writing a windows 8 app and use SQlite for Windows Runtime (so the .net wrapper for windows).

To try to optimise performance we want to set `pragma synchronous = off`, however when connecting using SQlite for Windows Runtime we cannot do this. The only connection we can make is by providing the Database Path and using for example:

```
var localConnect = new SQLiteConnection(SqliteData.DbPath);
```

(SqliteData is our class and it holds the path of course, we cannot pass anything but the path, so cannot add a connection string with settings with the path).

There is also the ability to pass `SQLiteOpenFlags` but none of these seem to relate to any of the settings we want.

What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it using Connection string.

```
String DBPath = @"Data Source=c:\temp\Sqlitedb.db;PRAGMA synchronous=OFF"
```